# DART HttpRequest does not provide authorization header for CORS OPTIONS request

Tags: dart, cors, dart-html

I try to do a POST request with HttpRequest (dart:html) to call a rest service secured with basic authentication.

```dart
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR
var url = "http://localhost:8082/xyz";
request.open("POST", url, async: false); // POST the data to the server

String username = "foo";
String password = "bar";
final auth = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(UTF8.encode("$username:$password"));

request.setRequestHeader('authorization',"Basic $auth");
request.setRequestHeader('content-type',"application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
String jsonData = '{"language":"dart"}'; // etc...

request.send(jsonData);  //exception 401 Unauthorized
```

Before performing the POST call the OPTIONS call is performed (issued by dart:html) without the authorization header. This leads into an 401 Unauthorized response.

> Request header:
>
> > Accept:*/* 
> >     Accept-Encoding:
> >     gzip,deflate,sdch
> >     Accept-Language:
> >     en-US,en;q=0.8
> >     Access-Control-Request-Headers:
> >     authorization, content-type, accept
> >     Access-Control-Request-Method:
> >     POST
> >     Cache-Control:
> >     max-age=0
> >     Connection:
> >     keep-alive
> >     Host:
> >     localhost:8082
> >     Origin:
> >     http://localhost:63342
> >     Referer:
> >     http://localhost:63342/dart_client/test/all_test.html
> >     User-Agent:
> >     Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.0 (Dart) Safari/537.36
>
> Reponse header:
>
> > Content-Length:
> >     0
> >     Date:
> >     Mon, 02 Feb 2015 23:33:58 GMT
> >     Server:
> >     Jetty(9.2.7.v20150116)
> >     WWW-Authenticate:
> >     basic realm="xyzrealm"

Is there a way to provide the authorization header to the OPTIONS call?

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OPTIONS` request is made by the browser automatically and you can't modify that request. The server needs to allow the `OPTIONS` preflight request without authentication.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0
The user credentials are excluded.

Comment: Thank you! You were right, the OPTIONS request is made by the browser. To enable the preflight request, i've needed to create a new SecurityHandler for the Jetty Server. As example See [link](https://code.launchpad.net/~nwilliams/akiban-server/cors-preflight-no-auth/+merge/161690)